# How to check if an array contains any undefined value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know whether my array contains any undefined value. My array is like this,
[image]

How to find it?
I tried this method but it doesn't read 'undefined'

```
 let newValues = []
 if(values.length === selectedCertifiedList.length){
   values && values.filter(v => v === (undefined ||  0 || null)).map(val => {
        newValues.push(val);
   })
 }
```

Comment: What are your exact requirements? Do you want value or index?

Comment: @ankitgupta, say correct what you want exactly, values or check contain undefined values available or not?

Comment: @Leya Have you got output or not?

Comment: I want to check if the array contains any undefined value, if it contains I want to stop a function.

Comment: arr.some(x=> x===undefined)

Comment: I tried this. But this condition only works when I enter any 2 digit number in any field. If I enter single-digit number in each field it returns wrong answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr.some(item => item === undefined)`

returns `true` if any item in the array is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = ['a', undefined, 'b']
arr.indexOf(undefined) !== -1  //true
```

It will return true if undefined present in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
const data = ['one', 0, 'two',  undefined, 'three'];
const checker = [null, undefined, 0]; //filtering conditions
const x = data.filter((item) => !checker.includes(item) )
console.log(data)
console.log(x)

//Output looks ["one","two","three"]
```